# In how many ways can you split 100 identical coins to 5 people, so that no one gets more than 50 coins?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can you split 100 identical coins to 5 people, so that no one gets more than 50 coins? I know the general formula : $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$
Can someone give me some directions?
I was thinking maybe put aside 50 coins first but then I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the total number of ways to distribute the coins, with no restriction. You know how to do that.

Now subtract the number of *bad* distributions, in which someone gets more than $50$ coins. The lucky person can be chosen in $5$ ways.

Say Alicia is the lucky person. We count the number of ways to distribute the coins, with Alicia getting $51$ or more. Give her $51$ coins. That leaves $49$ coins to be distributed among the **five** people, including Alicia. This can be done in $\binom{49+5-1}{5-1}$ ways.

So the total number of *bad* distributions is $5\binom{53}{4}$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: So the final answer is all the ways minus the bad ways right (what you wrote at the end) right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I like to concentrate on the logical structure of the argument and leave something for you to do.

Comment: But if now I have all the bad distributions of someone getting 51 coins... What about all the bad distributions of someone getting 52? 53? 54...

Comment: That *has been taken care of* in the solution, We gave Alicia  $51$ coins. Then (please see answer) we distributed $49$ coins between **five** people, **including Alicia**.  Thus Alicia might end up with $77$ coins, all cases are counted.  The complete answer to the problem is $\binom{104}{4}-5\cdot\binom{53}{4}$. (Well, then we could calculate, not interesting.)